# How to generate own docs locally using devdocs.io

Tags: documentation, thor

Our organization wants to experiment with using devdocs.io to integrate our API docs. I installed devdocs.io locally and have it running in my browser. I do:

```
$ thor list
assets
------
thor assets:clean [--keep=<n>] [--verbose]              # Clean old assets
thor assets:compile [--clean] [--keep=<n>] [--verbose]  # Compile all assets

console
-------
thor console:      # Start a REPL
thor console:docs  # Start a REPL in the "Docs" module

docs
----
thor docs:clean                                           # Delete documentation packages
thor docs:download (<doc> <doc>... | --all)               # Download documentations
thor docs:generate <doc> [--verbose] [--debug] [--force]  # Generate a documentation
thor docs:list                                            # List available documentations
thor docs:manifest                                        # Create the manifest
thor docs:package (<doc> <doc>... | --all)                # Package documentations
thor docs:page <doc> [path] [--verbose] [--debug]         # Generate a page (no indexing)

test
----
thor test:all  # Run all tests
```

which seems to indicate that you do  thor docs:generate and pass a "doc". What is a doc? A file path? A URL? A name? If I pass a URL, thor seems to think I am trying to execute a subcommand:

```
$ thor docs:generate http://host/path/to/resource

devdocs/lib/docs.rb:40:in `const_get': wrong constant name Http:::::::::HOST::Path::To::Resource:: (NameError)
```

What's up with this? Do I have to register the name of the docs I am generating somewhere and pass it that name instead? Basic documentation on how to this would be real helpful. I didn't see any. Could be I just missed it somewhere, but I did search the web and read the README.md file on github.

Comment: This may help [Adding documentations to DevDocs](https://github.com/Thibaut/devdocs/wiki/Adding-documentations-to-DevDocs)